# db_select() always returns uid =1: why?

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm doing a `db_select()` query of Commerce orders in Drupal 7.

```
$query = db_select('commerce_order', 'corder');
$query->fields('corder', array('order_id', 'uid'));
$query_result = $query->execute();
$results = $query_result->fetchAllAssoc('order_id');
dsm(print_r($results,TRUE));
dsm($results);
```

I execute this code in the devel/php page. `print_r()` prints out some actual results with the user ID; `dsm($results)` shows the user ID is always 1; my code always gets 1 for `$result[$order_id]->uid`.

The output of `dsm(print_r($results,TRUE))` is the following.

```
[89143] => stdClass Object
    (
        [order_id] => 89143
        [uid] => 62791
    )
```

`dsm($results)` gives the following.

> [image]

Does anyone know why it happens?

I'm trying to create a programmatically generated report, and I want the user ID to later lookup the user object.

```
if (count($results)) {
  foreach ($results as $order_id => $result) {
    try {
      $account = user_load($result->uid); // $result->uid always = 1
    }
  }
}
```

The code runs with a registered user, with full permissions for viewing/editing everything in the commerce order.

Comment: For clarity, I would use a variable like `$account` and not `$user` since that is a global in D7. See: https://www.drupal.org/node/2032447

Comment: yeah thanks...for clarity I"m not logged in as user 1 either

Comment: updated question to avoid the $user variable confusion